# react formik conditional render initial values

Tags: reactjs, if-statement, render, formik

I want to render a value if my Id is true if the Id is false the value shouldnt exist, is it possible to render what values  formik

```
initialValues={{
                    id:currentBankData.id || '',
                    name: currentBankData.name || '',
                    address: currentBankData.address || '',
                    country: currentBankData.country || '',
                    region: currentBankData.region || '',
                    city: currentBankData.city || '',
                    swiftCode: currentBankData.swiftCode || '',
                    routeCode: currentBankData.routeCode || '',
                    
                    //Example want to do something like this
if(Id){
    imageBinairyData: currentBankData.image ||'' ,
}else{
image: currentBankData.image || '',
}
                }}
```

Comment: it should be possible with just one field imageBinaryData : Id ? currentBankData.image ||'' : <something_else>. Why would you need image and imageBinaryData

Comment: it is to post and upadate data how I have it updated so can you not conditionally render a specific value

Comment: also I am am new so might also be a reason but can you send an example or link to help  been stuck on this for two days

Comment: but to render the value is that possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
initialValues={{
  id:currentBankData.id || '',
  name: currentBankData.name || '',
  address: currentBankData.address || '',
  country: currentBankData.country || '',
  region: currentBankData.region || '',
  city: currentBankData.city || '',
  swiftCode: currentBankData.swiftCode || '',
  routeCode: currentBankData.routeCode || '',
  [Id ? 'imageBinairyData' : 'image']: currentBankData.image || '',
}}
```